# Правильная передача текста по Ajax методом Post

Tags: javascript, php

```
text: "<?=$wall['text'])?>",
```

`$wall['text']` если содержит к примеру `"` или `\n`, то это разрушает конструкцию JS.

Как обработать `$wall['text']` перед передачей?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно передать json из php

`text: <?=json_encode($wall['text']));?>`